# How the camel recipientList forward the messages

Tags: multithreading, routes, apache-camel, messaging, integration-patterns

```
from("direct:A")
    .process(//processing here)
            .recipientList(//expression that return two recipients [direct:B, direct:C] )

from("direct:B")
    .process(//processing here)...


from("direct:C")
    .process(//processing here)...
```

`.from("direct:A")` behaves like a java method i.e the thread that calls it will continue to `process()`.

So what will happen in above case  ?

Let say Thread `t1` calls `from("direct:A")` then

`t1` will continue to `process()`

and then `t1` will enter into `recipientList()`

Now from here on-wards will `t1` call `from("direct:B")` and then call `from("direct:C")` synchronously

or

`direct:b` and `direct:c` will be called in two new thread asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) documentation for a lot more detail. By default it processes messages synchronously. You can use the parallel processing feature of the recipient list to run this concurrently. You can also define your own thread pools.

Go read the documentation it is in there.